# How to get RSA keyid/Fingerprint from RSA private Key using BouncyCastle C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am using BouncyCastle to read the RSA Private key, I want to get the fingerprint or unique key id from the private key.

below is the code

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(privateKey))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaPrivatekey;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passPhrase))
        {
            var privateKeyObject = new PemReader(reader, new PasswordFinder(passPhrase)).ReadObject();
            rsaPrivatekey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters) privateKeyObject;
        }
        else
        {
            var privateKeyObject = new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
            rsaPrivatekey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters) privateKeyObject;
        }
       /*here I want to get the Key Id or Fingerprint using 
       rsaPrivatekey object*/

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of anything called a 'fingerprint' or 'keyid' for an RSA private key. You would have to provide some context to your question to make it sensible.

Comment: Usually the ID is the SHA-1 or SHA-256 hash over the modulus, encoded as unsigned, big endian number in the minimum number of octets (bytes). This, of course, will give a public key the same ID as the private key so you can find matches (e.g. private key for a specific certificate). See the PKCS#11 specifications for more information. Be warned that most of .NET is little endian!